# cppzmq: Socket operation on non-socket when using zmq::send_multipart

Tags: python, zeromq, c11, pyzmq

Im new to `ZMQ` and trying to set a simple `PubSub pattern` between `CPP` publisher and `Python` Subscriber, my aim is to use the send more mechanism

can't quite understand what is the cause of the error and how to fix it, details below

this is the Publisher code:

```
zmq::context_t *context;

//  Socket to talk to clients
zmq::socket_t *publisher;
...
zmq_bind(this->publisher, this->externalPubLine.c_str()/*ipc:///tmp/MyPub*/);
...
std::array<zmq::const_buffer, 2> send_msgs = {
zmq::str_buffer("more messages !!! it's so fun"), // meta
zmq::const_buffer((const char *)(m->msg.get()), m->msg_size) // data
};
zmq::socket_ref sr = *this->publisher;
auto b = zmq::send_multipart(sr, send_msgs); //send multi part  <-- fails here
```

this is my subscriber code

```
subscriber.connect('ipc:///tmp/MyPub')
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')
while True:
    msg = subscriber.recv_multipart()
```

when running the `CPP` code it throws the following trace (running using `gdb`):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'
  what():  Socket operation on non-socket

Thread 4 "pub" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff01a5700 (LWP 16229)]
0x00007ffff68bd428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
54      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)  bt
#0  0x00007ffff68bd428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007ffff68bf02a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff720cdde in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7218896 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7218901 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7218b55 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00000000004ac0c4 in zmq::detail::socket_base::send (this=0x7ffff01a4cc8, buf=..., flags=zmq::send_flags::sndmore)
    at /home/vm/repo/my_zmq/pub/zmq/zmq.hpp:1827
#7  0x00000000004ac350 in zmq::send_multipart<std::array<zmq::const_buffer, 2ul>&, void> (s=..., msgs=..., flags=zmq::send_flags::none)
    at /home/vm/repo/my_zmq/pub/zmq/zmq_addon.hpp:181
```